# Filter maximum value from sql count query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I currently have the following query

```
SELECT organisation.organisationID, COUNT(organisation.organisationID)
FROM position, positionLocation, organisation
WHERE position.positionLocationID = positionLocation.positionLocationID AND
positionLocation.organisationID = organisation.organisationID AND
position.status = 'Open'
GROUP BY organisation.organisationID;
```

This query outputs

```
organisationID | countOrganisationID
1                3
3                2
5                3
```

I would like to display records that have max countOrganisationID. Ideally i would just like output the organisationID with its corresponding organisationName if possible.

Something along the lines of

```
organisationID | organisatioName
1                name1
5                name2
```

Any help would be appreciate

Thanks

Comment: You need to look at rank(), but it's not too hard. (sorry would post a proper answer, but it's late and it's sunday)

Comment: Sorry forgot to say, oracle 11g

I will look into rank() thanks for the tip

Any way to do it using max()?

Answer (score 5):

Barrett is right, RANK() is the way to go, e.g.:

```
SELECT organisationID, c FROM (
  SELECT organisationID
        ,c
        ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY c DESC) r
  FROM (
    SELECT organisation.organisationID
          ,COUNT(organisation.organisationID) AS c
    FROM position, positionLocation, organisation
    WHERE position.positionLocationID = positionLocation.positionLocationID
    AND positionLocation.organisationID = organisation.organisationID
    AND position.status = 'Open'
    GROUP BY organisation.organisationID
  )
) WHERE r = 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Could just subquery it:

```
WITH counts AS (
    SELECT organisation.organisationID
          ,organisation.organisationName
          ,COUNT(organisation.organisationID) the_count
      FROM position, positionLocation, organisation
      WHERE position.positionLocationID = positionLocation.positionLocationID
        AND positionLocation.organisationID = organisation.organisationID
        AND position.status = 'Open'
      GROUP BY organisation.organisationID, organisation.organisationName
)
SELECT organisationID, organisationName
  FROM counts
  WHERE the_count = (SELECT MAX(the_count) FROM counts)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
SELECT organisationID,  organisatioName
FROM position, positionLocation, organisation
WHERE position.positionLocationID = positionLocation.positionLocationID AND
positionLocation.organisationID = organisation.organisationID AND
position.status = 'Open'
AND COUNT(organisation.organisationID) =
    SELECT MAX(cnt) AS MaxCnt FROM
        SELECT organisation.organisationID, COUNT(organisation.organisationID) AS cnt
        FROM organisation
        WHERE position.status = 'Open'
        GROUP BY organisation.organisationID

GROUP BY organisation.organisationID, organisation.organisatioName;
```

Comment: @amitl Should organisations with an associated position.status = 'Closed' be included in the max count?